# WordPress Pages “allow comments” meta option can't be checked

Tags: pages, comments

I'm trying to allow comments on WordPress pages, but when I check the page's "Allow Comments" meta checkbox option ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Mbt.png ) and save page, it does NOT save settings, it returns to an UNCHECKED box again! Don't know why?!

My default discussion settings as the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rxmn.png

PS: it works well on POSTS, but PAGES does not!

Any ideas about how to fix that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: WordPress version is 4.1.1

Comment: Activate one of default themes (like Twenty Fifteen) and try to save that option. You will know if it is a theme-related issue. If it is, you should contact with theme support.

Comment: Thanks @macemmek, yes it was theme-related issue, I've contacted them, but I'm a web developer, so I may can fix it myself, if you can guide me to file/function.

Comment: You may start by searching for "comment_status" string within theme files in order to see if any operations are performed on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the [theme developers](http://thememotive.com) for helping me fixing it.

I'm posting the answer here in hope that it may helpes any person facing the same problem.

In **functions.php** there was a code to disable comments on **page.php**

Remove this part of code from **functions.php** to make the comments working on pages too:

```
    function default_comments_off( $data ) {
    if( $data['post_type'] == 'page') {
    $data['comment_status'] = 0;
    }

    return $data;
    }
    add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'default_comments_off' );
```